# rGraph y label generated wrong when data is 1

Tags: jquery, rgraph

[image: gene]

```
id: 'bar_active',
data: [0,1,0,0,0],
```

I have a bar graph generated using rgraph and passing data into it. My data pass is '[0,1,0,0,0]'. When this graph is generated the `Y Label` is generated incorrectly. I am expecting to get 1 only in the Y label but im getting dupicate 1 label.

1. Why is this happening?
2. How to correct this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Y scale values are being rounded. You can remedy this by setting:

```
scaleDecimals: 1
```

In order to get a decimal place on the Y scale.